# My Unity panel isn't the colour I want it to be

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When making a menu screen I noticed that the panel wasn't perfectly white.

**Menu Screen:**

[image: Play Button]

**These are my settings:**

[image: Settings]

I've tried making a .png image and adding it to the panel but that just makes the panel go black.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the source image is perfectly white?

Comment: The source image seems to be Unity's `Background` I remember to be slightly grey. If you still want rounded corners rather use the one called `Default UI` or something similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove Any Source Image You  Have In Your Panel, In Your Case I Saw That There Is A SourceImage Called Background, To Fix The Color Issue Remove It, The Source Image Also Has A Light Kind Of Gray Background Which Overrides The Color Of Image Component. **Keep The Source Image To None.**